# Can one host an angular.js based static blog on Github?

Tags: angularjs, github-pages

I know one can host a Jekyl based static site/blog via Github pages. **Can one do the same with a static site/blog based on AngularJS?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would say yes considering all the angular UI github pages are in fact angular apps with demos:

http://angular-ui.github.io/

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

etc

Comment: Incorporate Charlie's comment into your answer for mega points!

Comment: I answered the general question with a general answer. Perhaps if OP wants specifics they will ask more detailed questions.

Comment: Yes! You can host an AngularJS app on Github. Its awesome. You can even have a custom domain!

Answer (score 92):

You can but you can't use html5 mode (removes the # from urls). If you use html5 mode, you have to redirect all requests to the root url since its a single page app. Since you can't use server side code on GitHub pages, you can't do this. So, if you don't mind the # in the url, go for it. If you want to use html5 mode, you need to look for hosting elsewhere.

From the Angular docs...

```
"Using [html5] mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to 
 rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)"
```

**EDIT:**
You can make use of some clever hacks to make this work if you really want to. The hacks are outlined in detail [here](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages). In summary, you rename your index.html to 404.html and github will serve it at all routes

Comment: This answer prevented me from asking a question. +1 :)

Comment: What if you used Service Worker?

Answer (score 12):

There is one conflict between Jekyll and Angular to be aware of.

Liquid, which is included in Jekyll also uses `{{  }}` for evaluating expressions. To change the expressions that angular interprets (so it doesn't conflict with Liquid) use:

```
var myapp;
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config([
  '$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
    return $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{(').endSymbol(')}');
  }
]);
```

Check out [this blog post](http://alwayscoding.ca/momentos/2013/10/09/angular-and-liquid-expressions-in-jekyll/)

Comment: You can [turn off](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#configuring-jekyll) Jekyll by creating a file named `.nojekyll` in the root of your Page repository and pushing that file to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I recently played around with AngularJS/Typescript and github pages and was able to deploy the site.
Since AngularJS is just javascript, you can actually use any decent webserver, e.g. github pages.
Here is the [demo](http://trojan03.github.io).
You can find source code [here](https://github.com/trojan03/personal-website). This repository contains typescript source code which you have to compile in order to get the appropriate javascript file. Then you basically put this include this file into your index.html and you are done.