# AngularJS html5mode support on GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, github-pages

The question is: **does *GitHub pages* support AngularJS `html5mode`?**

I've found a [**www resource**](https://coderwall.com/p/kfomwa/angularjs-html5mode-on-github-pages) which states that it's possible to do that with 404 fallback page. Well, it seems like an erroneous solution, since each call will return 404 error. This would not be seo-friendly for sure. `html5mode` is supposed to need server-side support (to return the html entry point for each call).

So - is that possible to serve AngularJS html5mode on GitHub pages **the right way**?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post [Can one host an angular.js based static blog on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626326/can-one-host-an-angular-js-based-static-blog-on-github)

I have been trying the same thing with little success. To use html5Mode, you are better off just hosting a simple MEAN app/stack of choice to do so.