# AngularJS 404 error on json file on GitHub Pages

Tags: angularjs, github

I created a GitHub Pages project with AngularJS, the Angular content does not load from the json file, and I am getting a 404 error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  birds.json

It is supposed to be just a client-side app. What is going on here? Does it have something to do with html5mode?

[Repo](https://github.com/timothyausten/angular-birds)

[Demo](https://timothyausten.github.io/angular-birds)

Related Questions:

[Can one host an AngularJS based static blog on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626326/can-one-host-an-angular-js-based-static-blog-on-github)

[AngularJS html5mode support on GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287000/angularjs-html5mode-support-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `birds.json` lies in the `angular-birds` directory. Try to change

```
var promise = $http.get('/birds.json').then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
                });
```

to

```
var promise = $http.get('angular-birds/birds.json').then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
                });
```

You may check out this [AngularJS repository](https://github.com/trojan03/personal-website) which I used to build and deploy my own website on github pages. Here is the [demo](https://trojan03.github.io).

Comment: You were right. I had to add the sub-directory `angular-birds` in a few other places, too: `/angular-birds/slideshow-products.json`, and in `birds.html`, I had to update the link to: `/angular-birds/images/{{bird.img}}` I just don't know how I am going to remember that later on!

Comment: The link `/angular-birds/birds.json` has to have a preceding slash.